# Where is the salt on the OpenSSL RSA algorithm?

Tags: openssl, rsa, salt

I find salting technique for symmetric routines in OpenSSL with the option `-salt`. But I can't find salt option for the asymmetric RSA algorithm.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The [very rough] equivalent to salt in public key cryptography is randomized padding. Its called [Optimal asymmetric encryption padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) or OAEP. (Its not really random, but it looks random due to the use of a PRF).

Comment: Ok excuse me, i am a new user.

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. A lot of folks do the same. Try to ask questions on the appropriate site in the Stack Exchange network. To help you with that, we try and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A salt parameter makes only sense for password-based encryption. The password is used to derive the key to be used for encryption. When ever you pass a password to OpenSSL to encrypt something, you might also specify a salt to increase the input entropy of the whole process.

RSA is not password-based. The keys are generated in advance and used directly. So, there is simply no place to use a salt for RSA.

There is also a difference in the structure of symmetric keys and RSA keys. Keys for symmetric block ciphers are simply binary strings/arrays. They can easily be generated randomly or from a salted password. RSA keys on the other hand have a specific mathematical structure and cannot be purely random.

This is because one RSA key pair is used to encrypt the communication between two parties in one direction. One cannot simply generate the public key without the private key for RSA. They have to be generated at the same time. It wouldn't make sense to let one party generate the public key and the other the private key with a salt, because either

1. the keys would not be interoperable or
2. far worse, the public key holder would also be able to generate the private key along the way.

Comment: Hi @Artjom B, I like your answer specially the statement _RSA is not password-based. The keys are generated in advance and used directly. So, there is simply no place to use a salt for RSA_. However, when I look at Spring Security RSA implementation, class `RsaSecretEncryptor` method  `encrypt(...)` still expects `salt` as parameter, I can see it uses AES somehow. Can you point some references I could understand this better? Source code is here: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-rsa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/rsa/crypto/RsaSecretEncryptor.java

Comment: @LeoHolanda They use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) and use the salt to further randomize the already random symmetric key (`random`). This only makes sense to do when we're hashing passwords. When you look into the source code of `Encryptors.stronger` or `Encryptors.standard`, you see that the function actually expects a password and not a key. Symmetric keys have already high entropy which is why we don't need to hash/encrypt then further. Perhaps the authors thought that `KeyGenerators.secureRandom(16).generateKey()` is not random enough, but it is.